# Sequelize seed Data after updating migrations

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, migration

I am learning how to work with sequelize. Therefore I created a little project with a local DB.

Now, I created my first migration and have run it, it worked. Afterwards I created this seeder to add some Data to the table.

Well,I accidentally had two columns in the migration which I dont want, I realized it when seeding didnt work because of null values. -> To fix this, I generated another migration WITHOUT these 2 columns and run `sequelize db:migrate` which was successful `== 20211103094042-remove-some-columns: migrated (0.012s)`

after that, I wanted to add this test data with the seeder so I run: `sequelize db:seed:all`
-> this results in the same error as before: `ERROR: null value in column "createdAt" of relation "employees" violates not-null constraint` (createdAt was one of the columns i removed in the newest migration)

I am now stuck because I dont understand what went wrong. I hope you understand the Issue and might help me with it?
thank you very much!

Edit: I think I might have made a mistake in the new migration? I just didnt add the 2 unwanted columns. Does this not remove them from the table?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, turns out that im just not the brightest candle on the cake?

I "solved" it by simply run `sequelize db:migrate:undo` and afterwards running `sequelize db:migrate` again. the "undo" was executing the down steps of the migration which was "dropTable" in my case.